# Spring response entity image

Tags: spring, image, rest

I wrote a rest controller to return an image associated with a primary key. Now I wanted to load this image in the browser and I am running into issues:

(1) If I type a GET URL to the image the browser (FireFox and Chrome) don't display the image but they are seeing all the headers properly. Additionally firefox says "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

(2) If I used XMLHttpRequest to create get the image using the URL I get the image but it displays only partially (the bottom half is cut off and is set to transparent).

```
@GetMapping("/{featureId}/loadImage")
public ResponseEntity<byte []> loadImageForId(@PathVariable long featureId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    log.info("Getting image for feature id " + featureId);
    Feature feature = featureService.getFeatureById(featureId);
    File file = featureService.loadImageForFeature(feature);
    byte [] imageData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    inputStream.read(imageData);
    inputStream.close();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(...));
    headers.setContentLength(file.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.getName());
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(imageData, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: try this :  'image/jpeg' value as content type

Comment: which container do you use ? tomcat or something else?

Comment: Please explain how the binary data of the image is stored, is the filename of a file on the filesystem stored in the database or are the bytes in an array that is stored in the database?

Comment: Feature id stored in database table has a column for file system path. The path is used to locate the file in the file system. Then I build an input stream out of data bytes of the file as shown in the code above.

Comment: @Charizard_11, I am using Tomcat and the content type is obtained by probing the file type on the OS. I don't want to hardcode it to a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

if it is working on tomcat, you can use this tomcat's utility class :

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils
```

for example:

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
IOUtils.copy(is,response.getOutputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally after hours of debugging with curl etc, I was able to verify that the response body was not getting properly encoded image (nothing to do with the headers).

**This was caused due to the choice of `InputStream` and `OutputStream` objects.**

Instead of using `FileInputStream` I switched to using `ImageIO` and the underlying `BufferedImage` to write the output to the `ServletResponse` as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/{featureId}/loadImage")
public void loadImageForId(@PathVariable long featureId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    log.info("Getting image for feature id " + featureId);
    Feature feature = featureService.getFeatureById(featureId);
    File imageFile = featureService.loadImageForFeature(feature);
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType(Files.probeContentType(imageFile.toPath()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + imageFile.getName());
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    response.setContentType(mediaType.toString());
    response.setContentLength((int)imageFile.length());
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(imageFile), mediaType.getSubtype(), os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```